# MySQL efficiency: select on 5k records or error on 100?

Tags: mysql

My question is really about what the best practice is for a specific situation.

Every day, approximately 5k records are inserted into a table.  They are unique on 4 columns.  What's happening is that around 100 times during the process, the system processes the information again and tries to insert them and MySQL correctly returns an Integrity Constraint error.

Here is my question:
What is more efficient and a best practice:  Continue letting there be a error returned OR Run a select on ALL 5000 records BEFORE they are inserted to see if they already exist and if so, return the PK of the existing record?

Thanks for your time!

UPDATE:

These are 5k SINGLE inserts.

I am not currently handling the errors in any way, which I know is awful.  I'd be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.  Example is below.  The inserts just bomb and the system moves on to processing the next record.

**Warning**:  PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-Bananas 4 oz-Produce' for key 'store_id_2' in **/path/to/file/database.class.php** on line **53**

Comment: If your application handles the errors from the DB correctly then that is the faster and also an accurate solution.

Comment: @juergend: see updates, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some other options.

You can do:

```
insert ignore into . . .
```

This will ignore any errors so they don't get reported.  I don't really advise this, because it will ignore any type of error, and you just want to ignore one type.

You can also do:

```
insert into . . .
    on duplicate key update blah = blah;
```

This is where `blah` is some arbitrary column.  This is essentially `on duplicate key ignore`, so it does the update only when the constraint is violated -- which essentially ignores such violations.  There is the slight overhead of doing an update that really does nothing.  In the context of the `insert`, this is pretty minimal.

You can also do:

```
insert into . . .
    select . . .
    from dual
    where not exists (select 1 from t where keys = keyvalus being inserted);
```

This does an explicit test and only inserts when the values are not present.

The last two options have minimal overhead.  In any insert into the table, MySQL needs to look up the keys in the unique index anyway to guarantee uniqueness.  So, doing it explicitly isn't going to add much cost to the query.

Comment: I went with insert into . . .
    on duplicate key update blah = blah;
It worked really well.  Thanks!